# Why Flink core node not releasing JVM Metaspace memory?

Tags: apache-flink, amazon-emr

I am running a 1.13.1 flink cluster, where I execute batch jobs which executes athena query and save the result in athena tables.

I submit these jobs multiple times in a day.

In every execution, cluster's used metaspace increase by 7MB and its never released.

This ends up with an OutOfMemoryError caused by Metaspace every few days and i need to restart the cluster to clean the metaspace

taskmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size is set to 24gb

Any idea of what could be causing this metaspace grow and why is it not released ?

I encountered few FLINK jira ticket's where claimed that issue is fixed but I still face the same issue.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-16408
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-19005

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when code you're using is holding onto classes. I had to fix something similar for a Flink job when the Hadoop file system got invoked (via Hudi). There were actually two problems:

1. Hadoop created a daemon thread that was never being terminated, and it was hanging onto a classloader, which hung onto classes.
2. Hadoop installed a JVM shutdown hook, which also was hanging onto a classloader.

Fixing both required some helicopter stunts - basically I added code to a Hudi-related Flink operator's `close()` method, which (a) found and interrupted the daemon thread, and (b) used reflexion to get access to the list of JVM shutdown hooks, and then explicitly called the Hadoop one.